# Check if var is set or exists in Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this function in a angular controller:

```
$scope.sendCompanyData = function() {
    delete $scope.company["step1Form"];
    delete $scope.company["step2Form"];
    delete $scope.standard_address["state"];

    $http.post(Routing.generate('create-company'), {
        'company': $scope.company,
        'standard_address': $scope.standard_address,
        'phone': $scope.phone,
        'courrier_address': $scope.courrier_address,
        'logoFileName': $scope.logoFileName,
        'mercantilDocFileName': $scope.mercantilFileName,
        'rifDocFileName': $scope.rifFileName,
        'standardAddressState': $scope.state.standard_address,
        'standardAddressCity': $scope.city.standard_address,
        'courrierState': $scope.courrierState.courrier_address,
        'courrierCity': $scope.courrierCity.courrier_address
    }).success(function(data) {
        if (!data.success) {
            if (!data.exception) {
                $scope.errors = data.errors;
            } else {
                $scope.errors = data.exception;
            }
        } else {
            $templateCache.removeAll();
            ClientUser.loginToCompany(data.companyId);

            if ($scope.mercantilFileName != "" && $scope.rifFileName != "") {
                $noty.success(Translator.trans('company.register_success'));
            } else {
                $noty.success(Translator.trans('company.register_document_missing'));
            }

            $location.path('/empresa/' + data.companyAlias);
        }
    }).error(function(data, status) {
        $scope.error = status;
    });

    $scope = angular.element($(".seller-layout.new")).scope();
    $scope.section = 'segundo-paso';
}
```

The problem related to this code is on this line `$scope.mercantilFileName != "" && $scope.rifFileName != ""` since this is not checked or never happen even if I don't send any value on that. I'm getting crazy with this and perhaps it's easy but the code always goes trough `else` sentence. Any help on this?

Comment: Try `===`, like `$scope.mercantilFileName !== "" && $scope.rifFileName !== ""`. And do console.log for these params and see what is its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
if ($scope.mercantilFileName && $scope.rifFileName) {...}
```

I think that $scope.mercantilFileNam is rather 'undefined' than an empty string("").

Comment: You're right that was the problem, the comparison should be with "undefined" rarer than empty string